# PHP List wont show in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p>Today's Date: <?php echo $date; ?></p>
<p>Are you applying for a day, evening, or weekend class?</p>

<select name="date" id="wclass">
<option value="day">day</option>
<option value="evening">Evening</option>
<option value="weekend">Weekend</option>
</select>


Program Start Date:

<div id="dates"></div>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#wclass").change(function ()
{
    if( $("#wclass").val() == 'day' )
    {
        $('#dates').html('<select name="date">\
            <option value="date1"><?php echo $start1; ?></option>\
            <option value="date2"><?php echo $start2; ?></option>\
            <option value="date3"><?php echo $start3; ?></option>\
            <option value="date4"><?php echo $start4; ?></option>\
            <option value="date5"><?php echo $start5; ?></option>\
            <option value="date6"><?php echo $start6; ?></option>\
            <option value="date7"><?php echo $start7; ?></option>\
        </select>');
    } 
 }); 
});
</script>
```

So my issue is that i cant get the dates to come up, the list wont show. If i put the listi in on its own, works like a charm. There an issue with the javascript?

This is what the browser gets:

```
 $('#dates').html('<select name="date">\
 <option value="date1">Aug 11</option>\
 <option value="date2">May 5</option>\
 <option value="date3">June 6</option>\ 
 <option value="date4">January 7</option>\
 <option value="date5">April 5</option>\
 <option value="date6">December 3</option>\
   <option value="date7">October 15</option>\
 </select>');
```

Comment: Show us the actual markup generated. It's quite possible that the browser is bungling up the newlines in that multiline string literal you're trying to build. Clean workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript/805755#805755

Comment: The code comes from his previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126039/display-php-using-javascript

Comment: @Matt Ball -- My money is against that being the problem.  I'm waiting to see the markup, but I'm betting on the $start variables contain HTML characters by accident.

Comment: they are html, they are html and they are dates. Are u asking to see the content of the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are listening to the `change` event, your list will only show up if you select `evening` or `weekend`, and then change it back to `day`.

You can either force a change on initial load:

```
$("#wclass").change(function ()
{
    if( $("#wclass").val() == 'day' )
    {
        $('#dates').html('<select name="date">\
            <option value="date1"><?php echo $start1; ?></option>\
            <option value="date2"><?php echo $start2; ?></option>\
            <option value="date3"><?php echo $start3; ?></option>\
            <option value="date4"><?php echo $start4; ?></option>\
            <option value="date5"><?php echo $start5; ?></option>\
            <option value="date6"><?php echo $start6; ?></option>\
            <option value="date7"><?php echo $start7; ?></option>\
        </select>');
    } 
 }); 
}).val('day');
```

Or use then second solution I gave you here: [Display php using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126039/display-php-using-javascript/7126108#7126108)

Comment: @user860869 You have an error in your syntax: `$(document).ready(function() {
{`. That second `{` is extra, and is what's causing your Javascript error.

Answer (score 0):

Your string concatenation is wrong. Try this

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/seNPK/)**

```
$('#dates').html('<select name="date">'+
            '<option value="date1"><?php echo $start1; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="date2"><?php echo $start2; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="date3"><?php echo $start3; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="date4"><?php echo $start4; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="date5"><?php echo $start5; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="date6"><?php echo $start6; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="date7"><?php echo $start7; ?></option>'+
        '</select>');
```

Comment: @user860869 - Try this answer, you are missing the single quotes because of the string is not well formed and there must be js error on the page. Take a look in the console.

Comment: tried this, isnt working, the issue isnt the list, its getting it to show up in the html

Comment: Did you check the demo before down voting me?

Comment: Also in your code there was an extra `{` near `$(document).ready(function(){` I missed to mention that.

Comment: Did you remove the extra brace `{`? There is nothing to laugh dude we are trying to help you solve your problem.

Comment: ya i removed it, stil not the issue any way i can convert php variables to javascript